# Bash: what's the advantage of using exit ${1:0} instead of exit $1

Tags: bash

I found the following code snippet in Archlinux's mkinitcpio script.

```
cleanup() {
    if [[ $workdir ]]; then
        # when PRESET is set, we're in the main loop, not a worker process
        if (( SAVELIST )) && [[ -z $PRESET ]]; then
            msg "build directory saved in %s" "$workdir"                                                                                                                        
        else
            rm -rf "$workdir"
        fi
    fi

    exit ${1:0}
}
```

Is the `exit ${1:0}` here redundant? Why not just simply write `exit $1`. I tested this function with arguments such as 1, -1, 130, no difference between the simple and complex version.

Answer (score 2):

This allows it to be used with no argument (or an empty string argument) and result in `exit 0`. This is different from using `exit` by itself, because `exit` alone uses the exit status from the previous command. Even if `msg` or `rm` aren't expected to result in a status other than 0, this saves the author from having to think about this when changing the code.

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, it seems redundant as taking the substring of the variable from index 0 is... well the same value. However, an empty string to exit is the same as `exit 0`. Now, if it were `exit ${1:-0}` it would make perfect sense -- then 0 (success) would be the default exit value, and would be used in the absence of paramter `$1`. However, explicitly passing 0 isn't necessary.

Comment: yes, I knew the trick `exit ${1:-0} which makes zero as the default exit value. But this one is so different.

Answer (score 0):

To add to other answers: it's redundant in this case, because `exit` without any arguments would be have the same way as `exit 0`. Therefore `exit $1` and `exit ${1:-0}` are effectively the same.